# MySQL Query won't stop running

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in MySQL that is basically returning lots of grouped results from a table with ~5 million rows. I am grouping by 8 separate things and am returning 20 or so columns, many of which are sum(case when()) calculations. I know it should take a long time, and my computer isn't the fastest (although it's not especially slow). But it has been running for 9 hours and still isn't finished. Is that normal? It seems like nothing should take this long.

Comment: 9 hours is too long, are there proper indices on those columns, you can post the table schema and query to take a look at

Comment: can you post your sql ? are you using a lot of sub queries ?

Comment: There are no indices. Knowing that, do you still think 9 hours is too long? I'm not really very proficient in SQL and didn't think to put indices on the columns.

Comment: yes you can add indices and try. also check execution plan and see where is the time spent by the query

Comment: As already noted, DEFINITELY INDEXES, and multiple columns can be used in single index.  Please post your query because structure can also be big impact on engine interpretation on how it handles the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Is that normal?**

**A:** For a query that produces a humongous intermediate resultset, it's possible for a query to run for a really long time, even over nine hours.

It's not abnormal for a query that does an unreasonable amount of work to take an unreasonably long time.

But we normally avoid writing queries that do an abnormal amount of work.

As to why the query is doing so much work... likely a very inefficient execution plan, not using indexes for JOIN operations, or a huge intermediate resultset.

From another session, you can do a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to verify that the query is actually running. The output will includes the elapsed time that the session has been in the current state...